# Angular materials - how start?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have angular materials test code:

```
<div class="radioButtondemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <p>Selected Value: <span class="radioValue">{{ data.group1 }}</span> </p>

    <md-radio-group ng-model="data.group1">

      <md-radio-button value="Apple" class="md-primary">Apple</md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button value="Banana"> Banana </md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button value="Mango">Mango</md-radio-button>

    </md-radio-group>

    <hr>

    <p>Selected Value: <span class="radioValue">{{ data.group2 }}</span></p>

    <md-radio-group ng-model="data.group2" class="md-primary">

        <md-radio-button ng-repeat="d in radioData" ng-value="d.value" ng-disabled=" d.isDisabled " ng-class="{'md-align-top-left': $index==1}">
            {{ d.label }}<br>
          <span class="ipsum" ng-if="$index == 1">
            Duis placerat lectus et justo mollis, nec sodales orci congue. Vestibulum semper non urna ac suscipit.
            Vestibulum tempor, ligula id laoreet hendrerit, massa augue iaculis magna,
            sit amet dapibus tortor ligula non nibh.
          </span>

        </md-radio-button>

    </md-radio-group>

    <p>
      <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="addItem()" type="button">Add</md-button>
      <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="removeItem()" type="button">Remove</md-button>
    </p>

    <hr>

    <p style="margin-bottom: 0;">Graphic radio buttons need to be labeled with the <code>aria-label</code> attribute.</p>
    <p style="margin-top: 0;">Selected Avatar: <span class="radioValue">{{ data.group3 }}</span></p>

    <md-radio-group ng-model="data.group3">
      <md-radio-button ng-repeat="it in avatarData" ng-value="it.value" aria-label="{{it.title}}">
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="{{it.id}}"></md-icon>
      </md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>
  </form>
</div>
```

https://material.angularjs.org/0.11.1/#/demo/material.components.radioButton

It's working fine from codepen, but I get errors when I try to open it locally.

I tried to install angular or put links to js/css from CDN but it does not work :(

Sb can help me?

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: i mean you are putting all that code into a <html> </html> at the very least right? and the angular script at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to add the html/body tags and scripts.
Try to add this localy, it should work.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPWKWy

HTML

```
 <html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
      </head>
      <body layout="column" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

   <!-- Content -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', function($scope, $mdSidenav){
  $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menuId) {
    $mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
  };

}]);
```

edit:
If this is the problem, and you really want to learn AngularJS, try finding a course on https://www.udemy.com/ 
They often give away great courses for free.

Comment: this code doestn work :( i try download zip and start:

Selected Value: {{ data.group1 }}

Apple
Banana
Mango

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Did you unzip it?

Download the zip from codepen. Open the zip file - make a new folder - drag everything over to that folder - open the index with a browser.

Comment: ye but not in 100%. Can u tell me why my code i "2 Answers" its doestn work?

Comment: The code you asked for will probably work if you download the zip, and unzip it. You probably forgot to unzip it the first time. 

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/epgGVM
Try to download this and unzip it. :)